# How to set background image url and gradient on two different properties?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm adding a gradient on top of a `background-image`with a single property:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url('/image-1.jpg');
```

All my elements with `class` `.gradient` have the gradient, but the image changes for each element so I wanted to know if I could set the gradient as a property of `.gradient` and then change the image url in each element.

```
<div class="gradient image-1"></div>
<div class="gradient image-2"></div>
<div class="gradient image-3"></div>
```

Something like this:

```
.gradient // Add the gradient just once
{
background-color: background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.image-1 // Change the image for each element
{
background-image: url('/image-1.jpg');
}
.image-2
{
background-image: url('/image-2.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can define and override only one of the multiple `background` layer, so you need to re declare for each..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aunbM/)

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 20px;
    background:  url('http://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png'), linear-gradient(to bottom, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%);
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background:  url('http://www.digitalkonline.com/Portals/86261/images/agree-icon.png'), linear-gradient(to bottom, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%)
}
```

---

The other way to achieve this is to have `background` on the parent element, and another `background` on the child element, so a nesting trick

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/aunbM/1/)

```
div.wrap {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #eee;
    margin: 20px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a90329 0%,#8f0222 44%,#6d0019 100%);
}

div.wrap div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

div.hold > div.wrap:nth-of-type(1) > div {
    background:  url('http://www.digitalkonline.com/Portals/86261/images/agree-icon.png');
}

div.hold > div.wrap:nth-of-type(2) > div {
    background:  url('https://www.google.com/images/icons/product/chrome-48.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work with gradient.
However when we want to add 2 images I use background-size:contain;

```
background-image: URL("../images/imageName1.png"), URL("../images/Icone/imageName2.png");
background-size:contain;
background-repeat: repeat-x, no-repeat;
```

The first repeat will be for the first image and so on.